# Ширина резинового списка

Tags: вёрстка, css

Есть некий горизонтальный список, где ширина отступа между элементами списка задана динамически (в %). Как сделать так, чтобы ul автоматически принимал ширину имеющихся в нем элементов? Т.е. если ширина элементов после ресайза 200px, то сам блок ul будет шириной 200px.

```
<ul>
    <li style="float:left;"></li>
    <li style="float:left;margin-left: 10%"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Может так?

```
ul { display: inline-block; }
```